# Romance comedy manhwa where a woman is reincarnated into a novel

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhwa I was reading once. It was a romance/comedy novel. I only remember how it started.

A woman was reincarnated into a novel where she had to take care of the emperor's or duke's son. She knew that her character will die at the end so she wanted to change it. I remember that the duke was going to take the child and her to his mansion.

The male lead had black hair, and the kid had gold. I also remember that there was a chapter in a train where someone wanted to kill them.

Comment: Oof... unfortunately, a lot of that is very generic, a number of manhwas involving a female protagonist being transported into a novel where they know their bad fate. Do you remember ethnicity? Hair color? Was the manhwa itself in color? Do you know what site you might have read it off of? When did you read it? Did it have a lot of chapters posted? Was there any magic in the setting?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. If an incorrect answer is posted, it's an excellent opportunity to [edit] detail into your question of parts that don't match that didn't make it into the original question, i.e. "It can't be *Spangler's Inventions* because it didn't start with her walking in on her fiancee, her dog, and a jar of peanut butter, and I remember now that all of the soldiers carried repeating crossbows."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Villainess Flips the Script!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainess-flips-the-script)*, aka *It's Time to Change the Genre*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-villainess-flips-the-script/info).

> I woke up inside my favorite novel, not as the protagonist, Luca Winterwald, but as Judith, his abusive aunt and **the first character to die**—time for a rewrite! I’ll hand Luca off to his loving, long-lost uncle as scripted, and then live my own life far from danger. At least, that was the plan. When his uncle arrives, Luca suddenly calls out, “Don’t leave!” Now, I must protect Luca from impending family tragedy, raise him to become the hero, and turn this villainess’s ending upside down!

[image: Cover image]

Cover shows the main characters; the black haired duke and his nephew with golden hair. He is not the duke's son, just an illegitimate child "of his blood".

The scene with the assassin takes place in chapter 13. After boarding a train to head to the duke's estate, they're attacked by an assassin.

[image]

Comment: YEESS this is manhwa I was reading thank you so much ❤️

Answer (score 2):

It could also be *[This Villainess Wants a Divorce!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/this-villainess-wants-a-divorce)*, also found on [this page](https://bookswide.com/villainess-manhwa-recommendations/) where I found the other one.

[image: Front cover of This Villainess Wants a Divorce!]

> We all hate the greedy villains hell-bent on sabotage. Enter Carnelia Easter, the awful secondary villainess of the romance I’m reading, who trapped the prince in marriage at the behest of the evil empress. I didn’t shed a tear when her head’s lopped off, but now I’m Carnelia! I gotta play this smart and convince him to divorce me instead! Still, between the prince, the empress, the heroine, the second prince, my terrible health... this story’s getting unpredictable. Will I survive after all?

Answer (score 0):

Might this be *[I Became the Villain’s Mother](https://myanimelist.net/manga/145596/I_Became_the_Villains_Mother)*?

[image: Front cover of I Became the Villain's Mother]

> Summoned into her favorite novel as the infamous Duchess Roselia Chade, Haena is bathed in riches, power, and a family of her own. Life couldn't be better, save for the small detail that her beloved stepson, Einspanner Chade, is also the evil mastermind destined to kill her. At this point in the story Ein is still just an adorable child yet to reach his cruel awakening, and so Roselia is determined to stop him from becoming a ruthless killer. But with the duke getting in her way and trying to poison his own son, safely raising a child that was primed for villainy may prove harder than she originally thought. The survival of both mother and child depends on whether Roselia can successfully rewrite their tragic ending!

Found with a search for `manhwa reincarnated novel "duke's son"`

Comment: I remember that ml had black hair kid had gold I also remember that there was a chapter in train when someone wanted to kill them..

Comment: @Kiyomi: So there was a chapter on a train? These sound like good details to edit into your question. :)